# Grouping unique items in a python list when only equality comparison is possible

Tags: python, graph

I have a large list of graphs created from the [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) module. Two graphs `g1, g2` are the "same" if the function [`is_isomorphic`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic):

```
nx.is_isomorphic(g1,g2)
```

returns `True`. This isn't enough information to create an ordering as I can only define `g1==g2` and hence I can't use a set or dict to group the items. Is there a neat way way to group the graphs so that all graphs in the same set are isomorphic?

Comment: Do you mean that you can't use a set/dict because your items aren't hashable?  They don't need to be orderable to use a dict/set.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- I assume they're not hashible, and that if they are, `g1` and `g2` don't have the same `hash` value... But the lack of ordering also cuts out the other typical solution which is `sorted` + `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to avoid a brute force comparison over already seen groups, although you can minimize the number of comparisons by binning into groups based on graph properties which can rule out isomorphism (number of nodes, edges, degree sequence, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way:

```
groups = []
for graph in graphs:
    # check if this graph is isomorphic to any of our groups so far
    for group in groups:
        # we only need to check one graph from each group, since isomorphism is transitive
        if networkx.is_isomorphic(graph, group[0]):
            # if isomorphic, put this graph in this group
            group.append(graph)
            break
    else:
        # if none were isomorphic, make a new group
        groups.append([graph])
```

This creates a list of lists, with each sublist containing groups that are isomorphic to each other.

There are possible tweaks to this that could improve performance in some cases.  For instance, you could try first grouping the graphs (maybe by sorting) according to the number of nodes they have (their order).  Since graphs with different orders can't be isomorphic, you could potentially cut some corners by only checking for isomorphism among equally-sized graphs.